# python - get a list of first values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so:

```
look_up = {1: ('January', str(now.year + 1) + '-01-01', '2020-01-31', 'E'),
           2: ('February', str(now.year + 1) + '-02-01', '2020-02-29', 'F'),
           3: ('March', str(now.year + 1) + '-03-01', '2020-03-31', 'G'),
           4: ('April', str(now.year + 1) + '-04-01', '2020-04-30', 'H'),
           5: ('May', str(now.year + 1) + '-05-01', '2020-05-31', 'I'),
           6: ('June', str(now.year + 1) + '-06-01', '2020-06-30', 'J'),
           7: ('July', str(now.year + 1) + '-07-01', '2020-07-31', 'K'),
           8: ('August', str(now.year + 1) + '-08-01', '2020-08-31', 'L'),
           9: ('September', str(now.year + 1) + '-09-01', '2020-09-30', 'M'),
           10: ('October', str(now.year) + '-10-01', '2019-10-31', 'N'),
           11: ('November', str(now.year) + '-11-01', '2019-11-30', 'O'),
           12: ('December', str(now.year) + '-12-01', '2019-12-31', 'P')}
```

I would like to create a list from it containing just the firs value position, in this case a list of the months. How can I do this?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I recommend taking a look at something like Pandas. From the look of that data, and your question, I think it could be quite useful.

Comment: Converting his dictionary to a pandas dataframe just to get a list of the months would be overkill imo

Answer (score 5):

```
date_list = [ value[0] for value in look_up.values()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we are

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

look_up = {1: ('January', str(now.year + 1) + '-01-01', '2020-01-31', 'E'),
           2: ('February', str(now.year + 1) + '-02-01', '2020-02-29', 'F'),
           3: ('March', str(now.year + 1) + '-03-01', '2020-03-31', 'G'),
           4: ('April', str(now.year + 1) + '-04-01', '2020-04-30', 'H'),
           5: ('May', str(now.year + 1) + '-05-01', '2020-05-31', 'I'),
           6: ('June', str(now.year + 1) + '-06-01', '2020-06-30', 'J'),
           7: ('July', str(now.year + 1) + '-07-01', '2020-07-31', 'K'),
           8: ('August', str(now.year + 1) + '-08-01', '2020-08-31', 'L'),
           9: ('September', str(now.year + 1) + '-09-01', '2020-09-30', 'M'),
           10: ('October', str(now.year) + '-10-01', '2019-10-31', 'N'),
           11: ('November', str(now.year) + '-11-01', '2019-11-30', 'O'),
           12: ('December', str(now.year) + '-12-01', '2019-12-31', 'P')}

print([x[0] for x in look_up.values()])
```

Output

```
python test123.py
['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: why did you use `datetime` module?

Comment: I had the same thought?

Comment: to make the source code runnable ... in the source inut was `now`. it was an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
my_list = []
for entry in look_up.keys():
    my_list.append(look_up[entry][0])

print(my_list)
```

Comment: This won't give you the months. This will input the whole value of each key.

Comment: I ran that code before answering (thouhg the alex067 is better IMHO), and the result is: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']... Not the best way, but it is what the OP was asking for, right?

Comment: Oh, you are alex067... didn't realize! Well, your answer is simpler... I was writting and testing my answer while you were posting yours. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways, for example you take all the values of dictionary with `values()` function, and the with a for loop take only the first element of each tuple.

For a better guide and tips to the use of dictionary in python i give you this link

[Python Dictionary](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=m&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=1t1&utm_creative=255798340456&utm_targetid=aud-392016246653:dsa-473406574715&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9050720&gclid=CjwKCAiAis3vBRBdEiwAHXB29MIRL_gtvF4UubG8L6jPwm4_dtqUu-3CeA3skHnG6MP5rM46sYhShRoCGu4QAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
month_list = [value[0] for key, value in look_up.items()]
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `month_list = [value[0] for value in look_up.values()]`